# Creating two business account in paypal standard

Tags: magento, paypal, account

Can anyone tell me how can i create two business accounts? Actually, i want functionality like this, if my cart total becomes greater than 100USD than i want to pass it to my first merchant account else want to pass second merchant email. I know, its feasible. When page is redirected to paypal i have to pass different emails based on cart total.I want to create a saparate module by which i can provide two merchant emails , so these both entered emails can be used based on cart total.TIA, any help?

Comment: You should check the Paypal T&Cs if they actually allow you to have more than one business account.

Comment: Actually i m having two sendbox merchant account, i have already checked out using these two different accounts, amount is deducted from buyers account. But now i want to use both of them based on cart total. I can enter only one email in paypal setting in admin->config,I want to get two email address and want to make change in block of redirect.php.But thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create system.xml and paste

```
<config>
  <sections>
    <paypal>
        <groups>
            <account translate="label">
                <label>Merchant Account</label>
                <fieldset_css>paypal-config</fieldset_css>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <fields>
                    <business_account2 translate="label comment tooltip">
                        <label>Email Associated with PayPal Merchant Account more than 5 amount</label>
                        <comment><![CDATA[<a href="http://www.magentocommerce.com/paypal">Start accepting payments via PayPal!</a>]]></comment>
                        <tooltip>Don't have a PayPal account? Simply enter your email address.</tooltip>
                        <config_path>paypal/general/business_account2</config_path>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        <frontend_class>validate-email</frontend_class>
                    </business_account2>
                </fields>
            </account>
        </groups>
    </paypal>
  </sections>
</config>
```

And create config.xml and paste

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_CustomPaypal>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <depends>
            <!-- no dependencies -->
            </depends>
        </My_CustomPaypal>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
          <paypal>
              <rewrite>
                  <standard>My_CustomPaypal_Model_Standard</standard>
              </rewrite>
          </paypal>
        </models>
        <resources />
        <extraconfig />
        <blocks />
    </global>
</config>
```

Then override standard.php and declare `getStandardCheckoutFormFields()` method in which have to put logic as written in above comment. You will surely get error of private method `_getAggregatedCartSummary()` so redefine as it is as in core just scope is public. And finished.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109783/magento-multiple-authorize-net-gateways/5110585#5110585) regarding using two Authorize.net accounts. The concept for Paypal is the same. In the model `Mage_Paypal_Model_Standard`, there is a method called `getConfig`:

```
/**
 * Config instance getter
 * @return Mage_Paypal_Model_Config
 */
public function getConfig()
{
    if (null === $this->_config) {
        $params = array($this->_code);
        if ($store = $this->getStore()) {
            $params[] = is_object($store) ? $store->getId() : $store;
        }
        $this->_config = Mage::getModel('paypal/config', $params);
    }
    return $this->_config;
}
```

This looks like your best bet for an override. At this point you should be able to call:

```
$this->getCheckout()->getQuote();
```

to get your quote object. Use that to decide which Paypal information to load. Save that paypal information in the database under an alternate path (say `paypal/config_alt`) and return as necessary.

Hope that helps!

Comment: thx joseph, i appreciate you, but actually i want to provide two email address so admin can enter two email, by making changes to system.xml its possible. Now look at getStandardCheckoutFormFields() in standard.php uses $api = Mage::getModel('paypal/api_standard')->setConfigObject($this->getConfig()); so that api_standard can be get,here config is used. Now in this function getStandardCheckoutRequest() is called,from here business_account 2 is not returned, exactly. second email is stored in core_config_data as having path = 'paypal/general/business_account2'.

Comment: getStandardCheckoutFormFields() this function is used in block/redirect.php to provide variables to paypal. Now i want to override model that defines getStandardCheckoutFormFields() and returns variable business as per my requirement.

Comment: And i want final total including everything for that i think i have to use Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();, right?

Comment: If you write in getStandardCheckoutRequest() in $request['business2'] = 'test.com'; then it will return it to block/redirect.php and based on condition over there email can be changed. but i dont know how to get value from core_config_data where path i have inserted in it.TIA

Comment: yoooo i got data using this Mage::getStoreConfig('paypal/general/business_account2');

Answer (score 0):

Finally,I have added in system.xml after  tag as

```
<business_account2 translate="label comment tooltip">
    <label>Email Associated with PayPal Merchant Account more than 100 amount</label>
    <comment><![CDATA[<a href="http://www.magentocommerce.com/paypal">Start accepting payments via PayPal!</a>]]></comment>
    <tooltip>Don't have a PayPal account? Simply enter your email address.</tooltip>
    <config_path>paypal/general/business_account2</config_path>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
    <frontend_class>validate-email</frontend_class>
</business_account2>
```

After creating this and save config,you can see in core_config_data table that there is a path set at last as 'paypal/general/business_account2'. Now change getStandardCheckoutFormFields() as

```
$business2 = Mage::getStoreConfig('paypal/general/business_account2');
$grandTotal = $order->getGrandTotal();
if($grandTotal >= 100) {
    unset($result['business']);
    $result['business'] = $business2;
}
```

after `$result = $api->getStandardCheckoutRequest();` in Payment/Model/Standard.php, I have made these changes in Core files, But as you all know i have to create this using local folder.I hope this may help you.